"ARIA attribute unsupported or prohibited issue" in Kendo component
I'm facing an Accessibility issue with the Kendo Sortable component in my project. Specifically, I'm encountering a warning related to ARIA attributes. The warning message is:
I am using the Siteimprove tool to check the accessibility of my application, while I am running the accessibility test in my application, I am facing an issue called "ARIA attribute unsupported or prohibited issue"
Below are the error messages
------------------------------------
Siteimprove tool test report Screenshot - Siteimprove tool test report
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
WAI-ARIA authoring practices ARIA attribute unsupported or prohibited
An ARIA attribute has been specified that is either not supported or is prohibited, on this type of element."
aria-disabled on div  "
"Use supported states and properties only.and Use non-prohibited states and properties only."
ARIA attribute unsupported or prohibited → WAI-ARIA authoring practices
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Code which was using in HTML component
        <kendo-sortable [kendoSortableBinding]="activeSessionCur" [animation]="true"
          (dragEnd)="onDragEnd($event)" [emptyItemClass]="'secession-empty-state'" [emptyText]="'There are no active sessions'">
          <ng-template let-item="item">
            <div class="last-visited-case"  >
              <button aria-label="Remove" title="Remove" (click)="deleteActiveSession(item)"
                kendoButton icon="close" look="flat" class="last-visited-case-close"></button>
              <p class="last-visited-case-heading" role="region" attr.aria-label="{{item.clientName}}" (click)="onCaseClicked(item)" title="{{ item.clientName }}"><strong>{{ item.clientName }}</strong>
              </p>
              <p class="last-visited-case-details" role="region" attr.aria-label="ID: {{ item.clientId ?? '000' }}" (click)="onCaseClicked(item)" title="ID: {{ item.clientId ?? '000' }}">ID {{ item.clientId ?? '000' }}</p>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-sortable>

-------------------------------------------------------
Code that was generated dynamically in Browser inspect window
Kendo dynamically generate code in browser inspect window  - Kendo dynamically generated HTML code in the Inspect window
<kendo-sortable _ngcontent-ng-c1140897335="" dir="ltr" role="list" style="touch-action: none;">
      <div kendodraggable="" role="listitem" aria-grabbed="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-keyshortcuts=""
            aria-dropeffect="move" data-sortable-item="true" data-sortable-index="0" data-sortable-id="0"
            style="user-select: none;">
            <div _ngcontent-ng-c1140897335="" class="last-visited-case"><button _ngcontent-ng-c1140897335=""
                        aria-label="Remove" title="Remove" kendobutton="" icon="close" look="flat"
                        class="last-visited-case-close k-button k-icon-button k-button-md k-rounded-md k-button-flat-base k-button-flat"
                        role="button" aria-disabled="false" dir="ltr"><kendo-icon-wrapper innercssclass="k-button-icon"
                              class="k-icon-wrapper-host"><kendo-icon class="k-i-close k-button-icon k-icon"
                                    aria-hidden="true"></kendo-icon><!----><!----><!----><!----></kendo-icon-wrapper><!----><!----><!----><span
                              class="k-button-text"></span></button>
                  <p _ngcontent-ng-c1140897335="" role="region" class="last-visited-case-heading"
                        title="AutomationF180 AutomationL1" aria-label="AutomationF180 AutomationL1"><strong
                              _ngcontent-ng-c1140897335="">AutomationF180 AutomationL1</strong></p>
                  <p _ngcontent-ng-c1140897335="" role="region" class="last-visited-case-details" aria-label="ID: 47"
                        title="ID: 47">ID 47</p>
            </div><!----><!----><!---->
      </div>
</kendo-sortable>

Checked Documentation: I've gone through the Kendo UI documentation and siteimprove to see if there's any mention of this issue, but I couldn't find anything specific.

Attribute aria-disabled is of no use on the div and has no effect. You should remove it. If you want to tell screen readers that the remove button is disabled, you should put the aria-disabled attribute on the button instead.

Watch out @QuentinC, there are role attributes added to these divs.

Unfortunately the question is not very well formatted, and the actual error message is illegible. I can see two divs with roles listitem and button. aria-disabled is supported on buttons, but deprecated on listitem roles (as of ARIA 1.2). So that’s probably it, but that’s only a warning for now, not an error.

It’s not an issue for now, but it would be great if you raised a bug report over at the Kendo library to document the issue.

@Andy: I perfectly saw the listitem role. Attribute aria-disabled doesn't make sense for a list item anyway, since a list item is normally not focusable or interactive. So it should be removed.

The Siteimprove error message is concerning the aria-disabled attribute on the div with role="listitem":

Use supported states and properties only.

Now the listitem ARIA specification does list aria-disabled as an inherited state, but mentions that is has been “deprecated on this role in ARIA 1.2”.
Deprecated means that it will be removed in a future version, hence should be removed from code bases today, to avoid errors when the new ARIA version is released.
Siteimprove is probably referring to the lack of support by assistive technology.
In any case, it’s not a formal error (yet) to have this attribute, but it’s useless. In the interest of clean code, it should be removed, but it’s very likely not causing any issues with assistive technology.
For the next steps to take:
Fixing ARIA roles and states in, or adding keyboard accessibility to a 3rd party library via its API is not a viable option.
The APIs are rarely flexible enough to hook into the component’s life cycle to add these heavily state-dependent parts. Even in the rare case where it might be possible, it requires a lot of code which is a performance issue, and impacts maintenance.
For Kendo UI, I recommend the following approach:

Search on github if the issue is known. (I couldn’t find anything)
Create a new issue to document your test results. Provide the details which you posted on stack overflow, possibly more.

Then, it’s a matter of negotiation. Was accessibility in the contract with Kendo? Are they obliged to fix any a11y issue? Do they claim accessibility in their documentation? Can their library be seen as a product that needs to adhere to national accessibility regulations?
In this particular case, there wont be a high priority for now, if the issue is not causing any harm in assistive technology.

Hi @andy
Appreciate and thank you for your response! I tried your suggestion of searching on GitHub, and I also created a new issue in the Kendo forum as well as on GitHub to document my findings, but unfortunately, it hasn’t resolved the problem. The issue persists, and it seems more complex than expected. If you have any other insights or alternative suggestions, I'd love to hear them.
Thanks

That’s great, and hopefully it will get fixed some day. I’d say you did everything necessary. As Quentin mentioned as well: this is nothing to worry about. It’s not an issue, you should ignore the message. Is anything making this difficult? (:

Thank you for the reassurance! It’s good to know that it’s not something to worry about for now. I’ve done everything I can on my end, and I’ll keep an eye on any updates from the Kendo team. Nothing is making it particularly difficult at the moment, but I just wanted to be thorough in case it affects anything down the line and to make sure my application is bug and issue-free. Appreciate your help!, Thanks
